# What can prevent localization from working properly?

Tags: php, laravel, localization

Very basic setup:

**config/app.php:**

```
'locale' => 'de',
```

**routes/web.php:**

```php
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('test');
});
```

**resources/views/test.blade.php:**

```php
{{ app()->getLocale() }}
{{ __('Test material') }}
```

**lang/de.json:**

```json
{
    "Test material": "Testmaterial"
}
```

If I launch this in my app, I get:

```
de Test material
```

but I expect to see

```
de Testmaterial
```

If I add all provided code in a fresh laravel installation, it is working as expected.
In my app it is not and I am completely lost to find a place where I can look for an potential issue.

What I tried:

```
grep -r "Test material" .
./resources/views/test.blade.php:{{ __('Test material') }}
./lang/de.json:    "Test material": "Testmaterial"
```

to find duplicate keys, but there are none.
This is my folder structure of `lang`:

```
├── de.json
└── en
    ├── auth.php
    ├── pagination.php
    ├── passwords.php
    └── validation.php
```

What could prevent my translation from working?

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Version 9 with php 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is not on the correct place. It should be on `resources/lang/de.json`

Comment: Where you do go this information from? I followed the instruction here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization

Comment: Anyhow I tested your approach and it is working. Can you explain how, because the documentation is not mentioning the resources folder at all

Comment: @JanBoehmer In [starter template](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/8.x/resources/lang/en) for older Laravel version that was the place for languages. I see it was changed since L9 but I don't know why it's not working in your case :/

Comment: I don't know why is working with your approach  but it is. So thank you